# LonglistSelector can't scroll to last item when decrease height of it

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm a new in WP8.

I have a problem with longlistselector.

I have a longlistselector and I scroll it to last item. It's OK.

But when I decrease the height of it and scroll it to last item. but The longlistselector not scroll to the last item.

Code is:

```
PhotoHubLLS.Height = 300;
PhotoHubLLS.ScrollTo(PhotoHubLLS.ItemsSource[PhotoHubLLS.ItemsSource.Count - 1]);
```

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
PhotoHubLLS.SizeChanged += PhotoHubLLS_SizeChanged;
PhotoHubLLS.Height = 300;


//and the listener
void PhotoHubLLS_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PhotoHubLLS.SizeChanged -= PhotoHubLLS_SizeChanged;
    PhotoHubLLS.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        PhotoHubLLS.ScrollTo(PhotoHubLLS.ItemsSource[PhotoHubLLS.ItemsSource.Count - 1]);
    });
}
```

PS. this answer might be late, but I hope that it helps somebody :)